# After adding class name through jquery, click function not working, dynamic code not required

Tags: jquery

I don't want dynamic code. Initially I have given animation to move right to left, then i want to bring back to same position so I am replacing the css for bring back the portion.

for that reason I adding existing classes and adding new classes. but here after adding the class click function not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".leftIcon").click(function () {
        $(".leftPan").animate({left: '-250px'});
        $(".leftIcon i").css({'transform': 'rotate(-180deg)'});
        $(this).addClass("leftIcon-enLarged");
        $(this).removeClass("leftIcon");
    });

    $(".leftIcon-enLarged").click(function () {
        $(".leftPan").animate({left: '0px'});
        $(".leftIcon-enLarged i").css({'transform': 'rotate(-180deg)'});
        $(this).addClass("leftIcon");
        $(this).removeClass("leftIcon-enLarged");
    });

});
```

I dont have dynamic code.. just i need as static.

Comment: Please add your HTML code

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding new class dynamically, you have to use `$(document).on()` like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.leftIcon', function(){
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: Acutally I am developing as static page. while using like that its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use     `$(document).on('click', '.leftIcon-enLarged', function () {` instead?

Comment: Acutally I am developing as static page. while using like that its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(document).on('click')` event for dynamic content.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.leftIcon', function(){
        $(".leftPan").animate({left: '-250px'});
        $(".leftIcon i").css({'transform': 'rotate(-180deg)'});
        $(this).addClass("leftIcon-enLarged");
        $(this).removeClass("leftIcon");
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.leftIcon-enLarged', function(){
        $(".leftPan").animate({left: '0px'});
        $(".leftIcon-enLarged i").css({'transform': 'rotate(-180deg)'});
        $(this).addClass("leftIcon");
        $(this).removeClass("leftIcon-enLarged");
    });

});
```

Comment: I have tried withoug "$(document).ready(function () {" for that reason its not worked.

Comment: Hi, I have one more doubt